# npm add react-icons installation does not work

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am new to `React` and I try to download `react-icons`, but there is an error, which is different from those I had found here. Can you help, please?

`(base) Jana-MacBook-Air:react_project jb$ npm install react-icons --save`

Response:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jb/Desktop/react_project/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jb/Desktop/react_project/package.json'
npm WARN react-icons@4.1.0 requires a peer of react@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react_project No description
npm WARN react_project No repository field.
npm WARN react_project No README data
npm WARN react_project No license field.

+ react-icons@4.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 1 package in 1.875s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Looks like you have no project initialized at that folder, run `npm init` to start a project and then continue to install your packages.

Comment: You are not in the right directory where React app was installed. Just ‘cd’ to the right path and will work

Answer (score 0):

Well, do you have a `package.json` file in your root path of the project? The error is because that package have a peer dependency with `react` and because it's not finding the `package.json` file, then for the npm installation process, `react` it's not installed.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer I moved the package.json file in the root path, so this error is solved. But still, there is the: npm WARN react-icons@4.1.0 requires a peer of react@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.  don't know where to install peer dependencies and what does it mean?

Comment: @JanaBark Peer dependencies means that you need to install it by yourself. Just add it as any other package.